# Trying to populate user Document with post information, but I only have the user ID that I pushed manually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

so I am trying to get the title of the post, as when I display an array of posts made on user dashboard, I can only show the ID of the post when I redirect them, this works... but I think it would make more sense to have the TITLE in the place of that. Population does not seem to push the object into the array, maybe I am understanding population incorrectly, or there is a better way to go about it... thanks .

[image]

this is the react code for that list

```
                <ol>
                    { user ? user.posts.map((item,i) => (
                    <React.Fragment key ={i}>
                            <li><Link to={`/api/posts/item/${item}`}>{item}</Link></li>
                            <button onClick={() => { setId(item) }}>Delete this post</button>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )) : null }
                </ol>
```

this is the backend code which gave me the user ID , and the populate f(n)

```
        userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.author }, function(error, user) {

            const locationURL = req.files.map((item) => item.location);

            postModel.create({ ...req.body, image: locationURL }, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error);
                }

                user.posts.push(returnedDocuments._id);
                user.save((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });

            // this will populate the posts field in our userSchema (which contain the id references to our posts)

            userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.author }).populate('posts').exec((err, user) => {
                user.save((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });
```

in the user  document it looks like this, an array of ID's

```
[
    {
        "premium": false,
        "max_posts": 62,
        "posts_made": 57,
        "posts": [
            "5e21252ac51ac82838947875",
            "5e212a6c3b1619294832a3f2"
        ],
        "_id": "5e0fe3f33c2edb2f5824ddf2",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-04T01:01:39.840Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-17T03:36:36.086Z",
        "__v": 22
    }
]
```

in my userSchema I refrence Posts... but maybe I am doing it wrong and somehow can access that information...

```
let User = new Schema(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        premium: {
            type: Boolean,
            default:false
        },
        max_posts: {
            type: Number,
            default:3
        },
        posts_made: {
            type: Number,
            default:0
        },
        posts: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Post'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

Should I just call a axios request to get the names of those ID's that I have, I had that thought, but thought it might be unnessary calls to the DB which might become expensive. thanks.

Comment: can you add what you're getting in `user.posts`

Comment: I added the user document that is returned, that array keeps getting more ID's on create of posts

Comment: instead of array of id's are you able to send array of obj's something like this `[{ id: '1', title: 'title1'}, { id: '2', title: 'title2'}]`  from backend?

Comment: You can try to use join and get the names of the post through IDs.

Comment: I was reluctant to use object because it might break my code for a while, can you elaborate on join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are populating correctly, but not in the correct place. You should move the populate code inside the callback, and send the result like this.

```js
    postModel.create({ ...req.body, image: locationURL }, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }

        user.posts.push(returnedDocuments._id);

        user.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              throw new Error(err);
            }

            userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.author }).populate('posts').exec((err, user) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw new Error(err);
              }

              res.send(user); //user will have posts populated 
          });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sir can you comment is it benifical to populate or push the image title and ID , what is the less expensive / best practice?

Comment: @jcx3x this can be done simpler with a better schema design. If you are interested in I can later add info to the answer. By the way did your problem resolved?

Comment: yes I just pushed the title of the request, I got it from req.body when I made the post so I just pushed a object  ```  user.posts.push({ number: returnedDocuments._id, title: req.body.title }); ```  but I would be interested with your approach, as this is fine for this 1 category app, but I need to master schema, as I will be making a craigslist clone for my next project...if you can post some links for learning that would be awesome too :D

Comment: @jcx3x can you mark as answer and upvote? Later I will add the alternative schema design.

Comment: @jcx3x I recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781221/mongoose-express-how-to-properly-remove-create-store-data-that-are-referen/59784294#59784294). Can you check it please, I guess with that info you can do it yourself. If not I will help. Shortly, it is better to remove the posts reference from the user, because everytime a user posts, we weed to update both documents.

Comment: looks really interesting, for my current use case, I think its better to push an object into the users post array with relevant information,its the least DB calls for this simple use case, and also 1 call when post is deleted, but for next project I will try out your methods. thanks